# How was the non-Jewish city of Shushan "confounded"?

Tags: commentaries, megillat-esther

In [Megillat Esther, 3:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), after the king sends out his edict, the text says  וְהָעִ֥יר שׁוּשָׁ֖ן נָבֽוֹכָה, and the city of Shushan was confounded (or perturbed).

Clearly, the [Jews](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.15?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) were, but the non-Jews who, according to the Medrash, approached Jews and said "tomorrow I will kill you" did not seem perturbed. The only explanation I have seen is that the proclamation's contents were actually [unknown](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.15?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) in the city (having only been proclaimed in the "[fortress](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.15?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)" so everyone was confused. But if that is the case, then the non-Jews would have no reason to accost the Jews. Is there any explanation for why the non-Jews would be considered "n'vuchim"?

While I have a theory, I would like to know if any of the commentators can explain the "perturbed-ness" of the non-Jews.

Comment: Rashi and the other meforshim in mikraos gedolos seem to say it was the Jews who were upset.

Comment: @sabbahillel I read that but that just begs why the text would identify the whole city when the meaning is just a subgroup, whereas in other places, the Jews are identified as distinct when things applied to them alone.

Comment: it also could be asked "why refer to the city and not the inhabotants? The city does not have feelings."

Comment: Interesting observation. I'd say that the presence of Mordechay (or some say the whole Sanhedrin) makes Shushan a "Jewish city". Also, it makes a nice literary contrast, as we (the readers) associate ourselves with Shushan.

Comment: People refer to  entire cities all the time when they only mean the Jewish population.For example when it comes to minhagim people commonly say "everyone in name-a-city did/does" What they mean is everyone in the city who this makes a difference to .

Comment: The soul of the city was upset.

Comment: What's your theory?

Comment: @larry909 that the non-Jews were confounded by God's apparent abandoning of the Jews to allow them to be killed.

Comment: @rosends interesting. (Is it based on something?)

Comment: @larry909 nope, Just trying to find an explanation for a strange wording.

Comment: See the peirush of the Gr"a (and Yosef Lekach). I don't have them in front of me, but they bring an interesting Midrash that the Jewish artisans in the mostly _Jewish_ city of Shushan built a throne for King Achashverosh to imitate Shlomo Hamelech's throne. Since it could not be moved, the (ridiculous) King moved his capital there from Eilam. Picture the President moving the White House to Williamsburg. So he could sit on his throne and pretend to be King Solomon.

Comment: along the lines ....because the sanhedrin was in shushan ,even the gentiles in that city had some respect for jews  and were perturbed at the decree.           (the gemara says that it’s a wonder the goyim saw the rabbis yarchei kallah and stayed goyim)

Comment: I remember learning that Shushan was a predominantly Jewish city until Achashveirosh turned it into the capital city. It is possible the city was still majority Jewish or close to it.

Answer (score 1):

The medrash yalkutt says...
as soon as the deal was done,
many weird accidents started occurring
in SHUSHAN with no precedent or explanation .
maybe that is why all  r “perturbed”.

I think that people of shushan knew
how crazy the king was and also now
haman can convince him to do the most
outrageous ideas, were therefore “perturbed “

like  OMG - what’s next?

See reb shlomo kruger..
who says that the people when they
saw his drunken tirades and subsequent
dumb laws ,they said ....
OMG what is next !!!!